# How to get original string from the int generated by gethashcode

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I have generate a hash code as

```
string textBoxVal="Naresh";
int code =textBoxVal.GetHashCode();
textBox2.Text=code.ToString();
```

It has generated a integer value as -1078339947;

Now I want to get the Original name Naresh with this(-1078339947) hashcode. How can I do this.

Comment: You can't. That's the point of hashing.

Comment: If you want to take a string and generate a unique `int` identifier for it, what you're looking for is a database (of some sort, whether it be something that lives in memory for just the lifetime or your application to a full-blown database system), not a hash code.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use a `string instead of an `int` for this purpose? Since you can't do this using a standard hashcode, perhaps you can create an algorithm to generate a unique string code to use instead? (I guess this basically amounts to some form of encryption of the original data, instead of creating a hash from it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all practical purposes, you can't: there are lot less hash codes than there are strings, so there is more than one original value that would give your same hash code.

Hashing is, in reality, a one-way operation.  If someone refers to a reversible hash, this isn't a true hash (because a hash [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) reduces an input set into one of a smaller number of output values).  The closest operation to what you describe might be an encryption function - this would allow you to reverse the operation - but this is unlikely to generate as small a number as the 10-digit output in your question.

Comment: Then in what way I can convert string to int vice versa

Comment: For what purpose do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to give a number to a customer based on his name and date of  birth. and I want get the name back with that number.

Comment: An `int` has 2^32 possible values. A string longer than 4 unicode characters has way more than 2^32 possible characters. So it's not even possible to turn strings of 5 characters into unique ints, let alone longer strings.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't simply use an auto-incremented number?

Answer (score 3):

You just can't do that! A hash code doesn't contains all the necessary informations to convert it back to a string.

There is no even guarantee that `GetHashCode()` will return the same thing in different environments.

Check out *[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)*'s blog post [`Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode`](http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)

Comment: Then in what way I can convert string to int vice versa